# jQuery: extract first object from JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

This is my JSON, I'm trying to extract the second `campaigns->settings->subject_line` object. Here's my JSON:

```
{  
   "campaigns":[  
      {  
         "id":"xxxxx",
         "type":"regular",
         "create_time":"2015-07-09T08:08:17+00:00",
         "archive_url":"http://eepurl.com/xxxxxx",
         "status":"sent",
         "emails_sent":1,
         "send_time":"2015-07-09T08:11:31+00:00",
         "content_type":"template",
         "recipients":{  
            "list_id":"2753cf8604",
            "segment_opts":{  
               "match":"any",
               "conditions":[  
                  {  
                     "field":"EMAIL",
                     "op":"is",
                     "value":"xxxxx@outlook.com"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "settings":{  
            "subject_line":"asdasd - visioni sonore",
            "title":"asdad - visioni sonore",
            "from_name":"Luca ",
            "reply_to":"info@luca-.com",
            "use_conversation":false,
            "to_name":"*|FNAME|*",
            "folder_id":0,
            "authenticate":true,
            "auto_footer":false,
            "inline_css":false,
            "auto_tweet":false,
            "fb_comments":false,
            "timewarp":false,
            "template_id":60145,
            "drag_and_drop":true
         },
         "tracking":{  
            "opens":true,
            "html_clicks":true,
            "text_clicks":true,
            "goal_tracking":false,
            "ecomm360":false,
            "google_analytics":"",
            "clicktale":""
         },
         "report_summary":{  
            "opens":1,
            "unique_opens":1,
            "open_rate":1,
            "clicks":0,
            "subscriber_clicks":0,
            "click_rate":0
         },
         "delivery_status":{  
            "enabled":false
         },
         "_links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"parent",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Collection.json"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/51aa8bda6b",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Instance.json"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"delete",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxxx",
               "method":"DELETE"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"cancel_send",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxx/actions/cancel-send",
               "method":"POST"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"feedback",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/51aa8bda6b/feedback",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Feedback/Collection.json"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"xxxxx",
         "type":"regular",
         "create_time":"2015-07-09T08:05:08+00:00",
         "archive_url":"http://eepurl.com/xxxx",
         "status":"sent",
         "emails_sent":1,
         "send_time":"2015-07-09T08:08:08+00:00",
         "content_type":"template",
         "recipients":{  
            "list_id":"2753cf8604",
            "segment_opts":{  
               "match":"any",
               "conditions":[  
                  {  
                     "field":"EMAIL",
                     "op":"is",
                     "value":"luca@outlook.com"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "settings":{  
            "subject_line":"Carri\u00e9res de Lumi\u00e9res - colonna sonora",
            "title":"Carri\u00e9res de Lumi\u00e9res - colonna sonora",
            "from_name":"Luca ",
            "reply_to":"info@luca-.com",
            "use_conversation":false,
            "to_name":"*|FNAME|*",
            "folder_id":0,
            "authenticate":true,
            "auto_footer":false,
            "inline_css":false,
            "auto_tweet":false,
            "fb_comments":false,
            "timewarp":false,
            "template_id":60145,
            "drag_and_drop":true
         },
         "tracking":{  
            "opens":true,
            "html_clicks":true,
            "text_clicks":true,
            "goal_tracking":false,
            "ecomm360":false,
            "google_analytics":"",
            "clicktale":""
         },
         "report_summary":{  
            "opens":1,
            "unique_opens":1,
            "open_rate":1,
            "clicks":0,
            "subscriber_clicks":0,
            "click_rate":0
         },
         "delivery_status":{  
            "enabled":false
         },
         "_links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"parent",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Collection.json"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxxx",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Instance.json"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"delete",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxxx",
               "method":"DELETE"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"cancel_send",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxx/actions/cancel-send",
               "method":"POST"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"feedback",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxxx/feedback",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Feedback/Collection.json"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"71392a197e",
         "type":"regular",
         "create_time":"2015-07-09T07:59:18+00:00",
         "archive_url":"http://eepurl.com/xxxx",
         "status":"sent",
         "emails_sent":1,
         "send_time":"2015-07-09T08:04:58+00:00",
         "content_type":"template",
         "recipients":{  
            "list_id":"2753cf8604",
            "segment_opts":{  
               "match":"any",
               "conditions":[  
                  {  
                     "field":"EMAIL",
                     "op":"is",
                     "value":"luca@outlook.com"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "settings":{  
            "subject_line":"Yerma",
            "title":"Yerma",
            "from_name":"Luca ",
            "reply_to":"info@luca-.com",
            "use_conversation":false,
            "to_name":"*|FNAME|*",
            "folder_id":0,
            "authenticate":true,
            "auto_footer":false,
            "inline_css":false,
            "auto_tweet":false,
            "fb_comments":false,
            "timewarp":false,
            "template_id":60145,
            "drag_and_drop":true
         },
         "tracking":{  
            "opens":true,
            "html_clicks":true,
            "text_clicks":true,
            "goal_tracking":false,
            "ecomm360":false,
            "google_analytics":"",
            "clicktale":""
         },
         "report_summary":{  
            "opens":1,
            "unique_opens":1,
            "open_rate":1,
            "clicks":0,
            "subscriber_clicks":0,
            "click_rate":0
         },
         "delivery_status":{  
            "enabled":false
         },
         "_links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"parent",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Collection.json"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/71392a197e",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Instance.json"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"delete",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/71392a197e",
               "method":"DELETE"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"cancel_send",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/xxxx/actions/cancel-send",
               "method":"POST"
            },
            {  
               "rel":"feedback",
               "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/71392a197e/feedback",
               "method":"GET",
               "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Feedback/Collection.json"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "total_items":3,
   "_links":[  
      {  
         "rel":"parent",
         "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/",
         "method":"GET",
         "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Root.json"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"self",
         "href":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns",
         "method":"GET",
         "targetSchema":"https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Collection.json"
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried with this but nothing happens:

```
$("#secondresult").html(data[0].campaigns.settings.subject_line);
```

I'd also need to convert to UTF-8 the `u00e9` in the object `Carri\u00e9res de Lumi\u00e9res - colonna sonora`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on JSON you've provide this should work

```
$("#secondresult").html(data.campaigns[0].settings.subject_line);
```

you are calling data ( is object not array ) and campaigns ( js array not object )